# Sound on system but pulseaudio access denied issue

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, pulse

I'm having an issue with PulseAudio and also since many days that give me some headaches...
I've to sound on my system, no problems with that (both firefox and Spotify works) but I've issues in the syslog that lead some software (snips in that case) to not load.

The command 'tail -f /var/log/syslog' give me the following result :

```
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[12853]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission non accordée
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[12853]: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Impossible d'accèder au verrou autonome.
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[12853]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[12856]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission non accordée
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[12856]: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Impossible d'accèder au verrou autonome.
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[12856]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
May 15 22:54:01 paulm-serveur snips-audio-server[12849]: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
```

And 'journalctl -b -r _COMM=pulseaudio' :

```
mai 15 22:58:03 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[13842]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
mai 15 22:58:03 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[13842]: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Impossible d'accèder au verrou autonome.
mai 15 22:58:03 paulm-serveur pulseaudio[13842]: [autospawn] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission non accordée
```

So I wandered arround the web, follow countless of topics and tutorials, purge and reinstall pulse, alsa ... But nothing seams to works...
As you may asks, here are the permissions of my home folder :

```
root@paulm-serveur:/home/paulm# ls -la /home
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 mai    5 18:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root  root  4096 mai   11 21:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x 28 paulm paulm 4096 mai   15 22:41 paulm
```

My user is part of the following groups :

```
paulm@paulm-serveur:~$ groups
paulm sys adm cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev lpadmin pulse pulse-access sambashare _snips pulse-rt
```

I add few modification on the pulse config :

```
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf
    daemonize = yes 

/etc/pulse/default.pa
    load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,7
    load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,3
```

And my asound.conf is :

```
pcm.!default {
    type pulse
    hint.description "Default Audio Device"
}
ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}

pcm.pulse {
    type pulse
}

ctl.pulse {
    type pulse
}
```

My sound output is an HDMI port on a Nvidia card.

Is there anything I've missed or seems to be out of place in my config?

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

76MPaul

Answer (score 0):

Check you home directory permissions.

Use

```
#sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER
```

to fix the pemissions.

Comment: The home directory already had the rights permissions ... I given up this issue when snips was bought by sonos. I migrate to Rhasspy and do not have the issue anymore.